# How to test if an input has only specific characters

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to make a script that tests id there are characters in the input that are not `A, T, C, G` and if there are than the input is false.

I dont have any clue how to start. I would love if someone could help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following function can check a string to find out if it only contains the characters A, T, C, and G.

```
def check_string(code):
    return all(character in {'A', 'T', 'C', 'G'} for character in code)
```

Comment: @NamrataTolani Thank you for your response! Have you provided enough information so others can verify your claim?

Comment: Sure & Sorry! If you try - check_string("book") it returns false. If I have understood the question correctly it should return true right?

Comment: Maybe you could try: return not(any(character in {'A', 'T', 'C', 'G'} for character in code)) in your style :)

Comment: @NamrataTolani My guess is that [C. Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8945665) wants to check if a string only contains genetic bases in a string. The function `check_string` returns `True` if the string only has valid bases in it -- `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = True 
nucl_dict = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'} 
n = input("Insert DNA seqence: ").upper() 
for c in n: 
    if(c in ("A", "T", "C", "G")): 
        output = False 
if(output == False):
    print('Issue detected please try again') 
    print(n) 
    print(''.join(nucl_dict.get(nucl, nucl) for nucl in n))
else:
    print("All good")
```

Comment: when I do this the output is the false massage 3 times and then n 2 times. why?

Comment: please share your input.

Comment: I have a mission to make a script that converts DNA sequances. thats my code: `output = True
nucl_dict = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
n = input("Insert DNA seqence: ").upper()
for c in n:
    if(c in ("A", "T", "C", "G")):
        output = False
        print('Issue detected please try again')
print(n)
print(''.join(nucl_dict.get(nucl, nucl) for nucl in n))`

Comment: and my output is `Insert DNA seqence:  atcgatccg
Issue detected please try again
Issue detected please try again
Issue detected please try again
Issue detected please try again
Issue detected please try again
Issue detected please try again
Issue detected please try again
Issue detected please try again
Issue detected please try again
ATCGATCCG
TAGCTAGGC`

Comment: I can't understand the indentation of your code. There is some trouble in the extra code that you have put.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i cant make it with spaces batween the lines

Comment: it basicly prints the false massage times the amount of letters

Comment: Ok I am editing my answer according to your new question.

Comment: Check out new code. Perhaps you were entering the messages in loop itself!

Answer (score 0):

Expressed using sets:

The `list` function takes a string and returns a list of its characters. The `set` function takes a list and returns a set (with duplicates discarded).

```
>>> def check_string(code):
...     return set(list('ACTG')).issuperset(set(list(code)))
... 
>>> check_string('IT')
False
>>> check_string('ACTG')
True
>>> check_string('')
True
>>> check_string('ACT')
True
```